# How to get value from table using Firebird trigger

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

I want to get a value from the table and compare it with inserted value in the Firebird trigger.
Here is my code.

```
SET TERM ^;

CREATE TRIGGER after_in_systab FOR SYSTEMTAB
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS

declare sys_code integer;
select sys_code from system_table;

BEGIN
    /* enter trigger code here */ 
    if(sys_code == NEW.SYSTEM_CODE) then
    insert into logs(log_detail)values('code matched');
    end
    
END^

SET TERM;^
```

Comment: Comparing of values with other tables in triggers is generally a bad idea. You must deeply understand its limitation related to transaction isolation before doing something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [`INTO` clause](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref30/firebird-30-language-reference.html#fblangref30-dml-select-into):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER after_in_systab FOR SYSTEMTAB
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
  declare sys_code integer;
BEGIN
  select sys_code from system_table into sys_code;
  if(sys_code == NEW.SYSTEM_CODE) then
  begin
    insert into logs(log_detail)values('code matched');
  end
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use a *singular select expression* instead.

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_in_systab FOR SYSTEMTAB
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
  declare sys_code integer;
BEGIN
  sys_code = (select sys_code from system_table);
  if(sys_code == NEW.SYSTEM_CODE) then
  begin
    insert into logs(log_detail)values('code matched');
  end
END
```

If your `select` returns...

- one single row or more, then it is the same as [Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68046035/976391) (error when multiple rows).
- not a single row, the expression would return `NULL` while Mark's statement would do nothing (no change of variable value)

You may also think SQL `SINGULAR` existence predicate and about how it is different from `EXISTS` one.

- [Firebird docs](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-commons-singular) - chapter *4.2.3. Existential Predicates*
- [Interbase docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/InterBase/2020/en/Using_SINGULAR), stemming from old pre-Firebird documentation.

You also have to make your mind clearly what should happen if the transaction was *rolled back* (because of any database or network error, or because an application commanded to `ROLLBACK` changes): should your LOG still contain a record about the data modification that was not persisted or should the LOG record vanish with the un-inserted data row it describes.

If former is the case you have to insert log records in [autonomous transaction](http://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-psql-inauton) (chapter 7.6.16).

Comment: Your third point is incorrect, using a `select .. into` producing multiple rows produces error _"multiple rows in singleton select"_, it does not select a random value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel indeed, retracted